# from an orthonormal basis of polynomials, my corresponding coordinate matrix is not orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

how could I do it?  do I just put the coordinates of each orthonormal polynomial vector into a column, w.r.t. the standard basis?

for example, if my orthonormal basis is

$$\{1, 2x, 3x^2\}$$

Then is the first column of my orthogonal matrix just

$$[1,0,0]^t$$

the second column

$$[0,2,0]^t$$

and third column

$$[0,0,3]^t$$?

the matrix is obviously *not* orthogonal, just by inspection, but my basis is orthonormal for some specified inner product.  so this is confusing me...

Answer (score 1):

> my basis $1,x,x^2$ is orthonormal for some specified inner product

is refuted in [Is there a representation of an inner product where monomials are orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311993/is-there-a-representation-of-an-inner-product-where-monomials-are-orthogonal)