# Generalization of monomial orthogonality?

Tags: orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1312012/39367) answer a simple ad-hoc inner product for monomials is defined, since they are known to be orthogonal:

> if $P = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n X^n$ and $Q = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n X^n$, then
>   $$\left\langle  P,Q  \right\rangle = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n b_n$$

My question is, is it legitimate to generalize the above to cases where the leading terms in the polynomials are not integer? For example:

if $P = X^\alpha\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n X^n$ and $Q = X^\beta\sum_{n \ge 0} b_n X^n$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ , then
$$\left\langle  P,Q  \right\rangle = \delta(\alpha-\beta)\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n b_n$$
Does this hold true? And if yes, how to prove that it does / where to read up on the proof?

Comment: Your definition does not seem to be well-defined to me. What's the inner product of $P = X^{\pi}$ and $Q = X^{\pi - 1} (X)$? In any case, I imagine the thing you intended to write down is to make $X^{\alpha}$ an orthonormal basis for some arbitrary collection of exponents $\alpha$, which works fine but I don't know of any applications of doing this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What if we define $X>0$, then on the principal branch $X^{\pi-1}X=X^\pi$, so that $P=Q$ in your example. However, I would like to have $\langle X^{2\pi},X^{\pi}\rangle=0$. You are saying that for a collection of exponents $\alpha$ one could define such an orthonormal basis. How would one make this rigorous?

Comment: my point is that according to your definition we would have $\langle P, Q \rangle = 0$ because $\pi \neq \pi-1$, despite the fact that $P = Q$; the problem is that the representation you use is not unique and the "inner product" depends on the choice of representation, so it's not well-defined. In general, if $V$ is any real or complex vector space and $B$ any basis of it (in your example, $V$ is polynomials with whatever exponents you want, and $B$ is polynomials with those exponents), then there's a unique inner product on $V$ with respect to which $B$ is orthonormal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, thank you for pointing this out!