# Solutions of $n$th derivative of $(x-a)^n(x-b)^n=0$

Tags: calculus

$$ a\neq b$$

Prove the next about the solution of this equation.

> $$
> \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x-a)^n(x-b)^n=0
> $$

1. All the solution of this equation from $a$ to $b$.
2. All the solution to an equation is different.

Probably, it is the problem to which Legendre polynomial is related.

Comment: What does (1.) mean? I just can't make sense of that. The same with (2.)...???

Comment: If I should guess, I'd say: (1) All $n$ solutions are elements of $[a,b]$. (2) All $n$ solutions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the change of variables 
$$
y=\frac{2}{b-a}\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
$$
After substitution and simplifications, we get
$$
\frac{d^n}{dy^n}(y^2-1)^n=0
$$
which is equivalent to $P_n(y)=0$, where $P_n$ is a Legendre polynomial. For Legendre polynomials, it is known that the roots are all different and are within $[-1,1]$; for details, see the discussion in [Roots of Legendre Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12160). Hence, the roots of the original equation are also different and are within the interval $[a,b]$.