# Zeros of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

One of the most important properties of Orthogonal polynomials is the ff.

> **Theorem:** If $\{p_n (x)\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of orthogonal polynomials on the interval $(a,b)$ with respect to the weight function $w(x)$, then the polynomial $p_n (x)$ has exactly $n$ real simple zeros in the interval $(a,b)$.

Can you prove it? Please do it for me. The proof included in aw.twi.tudelft.nl
/~koekoek/documents/wi4006/orthopoly.pdf is in shortcut form. I cant understand it.‎

Comment: Note you can use latex on this  site. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a proof class. (serious) OR, pick up "How to prove it"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/528150/61216