# Prove that these sets of polynomials have real and distinct roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots, orthogonal-polynomials

Can anyone tell me if the following set of polynomials have a special name?
$$P_{0}(x)=1,P_{1}(x)=x$$
$$P_{n}(x)=xP_{n-1}-P_{n-2}$$
The above gives:
$$P_{2}(x)=x^2-1;P_{3}(x)=x^3-2x;P_{4}(x)=x^4-3x^2+1;P_{5}(x)=x^5-4x^3+3x$$
So $P_{n}(x)$ has parity $(-1)^n$. I was trying to find out whether they are orthogonal, but couldn't find a suitable weight function. My main concern is to prove that $P_{n}(x)$ has n distinct real roots, all larger than or equal to -2.

Comment: Alll roots cannot be less than -2. In fact for all your examples ($n=1..5)$ all roots are larger than $-2$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant I needed them to be larger than -2.

Comment: In fact you can claim that all roots are larger than $-2$ and less than $2$.

Comment: For general n? How exactly?

Comment: Generally the roots of the polynomial $P_n(x)$ are $2\cos\frac{k}{n+1}\pi$, with $k=1..n$. From this it is evident that they all are real, distinct and satisfy aforementioned inequality.

Comment: How did you find those roots?

Comment: I will write down the solution as soon as I have enough time for this. However it is quite complicated. Are you really interested in this or your task is just to demonstrate that the roots are real and distinct?

Comment: I need to demonstrate that the roots are real and distinct and larger than -2, but for that I will need the proof won't I? I will be greatly obliged if you could write it down or give me a reliable reference.

Comment: Done in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomials are indeed a special case of classical orthogonal polynomials. 
According to [Abramowitz/Stegun 22.7.6](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_782.htm) you have 
$$P_n(x) = S_n(x)= U_ n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
where $U_n(x)$ is the well-known Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.

The weight function for the interval $(-2,2)$ is 
$$w(x)=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{1/2}$$

And of course this means that the root are simple, distinct and located in the interval $(-2,2).$ For a proof  see e.g. my answer
[Proof the Legendre polynomial $P_n$ has $n$ distinct real zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527140/proof-the-legendre-polynomial-p-n-has-n-distinct-real-zeros/528150#528150) .

---

The orthogonality of $P_n$ follows from the correspending property of $U_n$ and $\sin$ , see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042793901485:

With $x=\cos\theta$ and $\sin \theta = (1-x^2)^{1/2}$ you have
$$U_n(\cos \theta) = \frac{\sin\big((n{+}1)\theta\big)}{\sin\theta}$$ 
so $$(1-x^2)^{1/2}U_n(x) = \sin\big((n{+}1)\theta\big)$$

(Although I did not see any fully formulated proof yet, maybe a direct proof from the recursion can be modelled after https://planetmath.org/orthogonalityofchebyshevpolynomialsfromrecursion)

Comment: Is there a simple proof that $P_n(x)$ defined by the given recurrence relation are orthogonal on $(-2,2)$ with the weight function $w(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

In what follows the explicit expression for the roots of the polynomials $P_n(x)$ will be derived. The statement "the roots are all distinct, real and less than 2 by absolute value" follows immideately.

---

Consider a family of $n\times n$ bidiagonal matrices:
$$\begin{align}
A^{(n)}_{ij}=&\delta_{i-j,1}+\delta_{j-i,1},
\end{align}\tag{1}$$
given below for $n=5$ as example:
$$
A^{(5)}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Lemma 1.** The eigenvalues of the matrix (1) are:
$$
\begin{align} \lambda_m=2\cos\frac{\pi m}{n+1},&
\text{with associated eigenvectors } u_{mk}=\sin\frac{\pi m}{n+1}k,
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
where $m$ and $k$ run from 1 to $n$.

Though it would suffice for the proof to let the matrix $A$ act on the given vectors, we present below an extended "constructive" version.

Assume the elements of an eigenvector $u$ have the form:
$$
u_k=e^{\alpha k}+ae^{-\alpha k},\tag{3}
$$
with some parameters $a$ and $\alpha$, which are to be found.

Obviously for all $k=2\dots(n-1)$
$$
(Au)_k=\left(e^{\alpha k}+ae^{-\alpha k}\right)\left(e^\alpha+e^{-\alpha}\right)
=\left(e^\alpha+e^{-\alpha}\right)u_k.\tag{4}$$

Thus it remains only to find such $a$ and $\alpha$ that the equation (4) is satisfied for $k=1$ and $k=n$ as well.

For $k=1$:
$$
e^{\alpha 2}+ae^{-\alpha 2}=\left(e^\alpha+e^{-\alpha}\right)\left(e^\alpha+a e^{-\alpha}\right)
\Leftrightarrow
1+a=0.\tag{5}
$$

For $k=n$:
$$
e^{\alpha (n-1)}+ae^{-\alpha(n-1)}=\left(e^\alpha+e^{-\alpha}\right)\left(e^{\alpha n}+a e^{-\alpha n}\right)
\Leftrightarrow e^{\alpha (n+1)}+ae^{-\alpha(n+1)}=0.\tag{6}
$$

It follows: $a=-1$, $\alpha=\frac{\pi m}{n+1}i$, where $m$ is an integer number. Plugging the values into (3) and (4) one obtains (2).

As all $n$ eigenvalues are distinct, Lemma 1 is proved.

**Lemma 2.** The characteristic polynomials of *negated* matrix (1):
$$
Q_n(x)\equiv\left|A^{(n)}+x I^{(n)}\right|,
$$
where $I^{(n)}$ is $n\times n$ dimensional identity matrix, are the polynomials in question:
$$Q_n(x)=P_n(x)\tag{7}.$$

For $n=1$ and $n=2$ the equality (7) is obvious. Assume that (7) is valid for all $n<N$. Then it is valid for $n=N$ as well.

Indeed, applying the Laplace expansion to matrix $A^{(N)}$ (with $N>2$) one readily obtains:
$$
Q_N(x)=x Q_{N-1}(x)-Q_{N-2}(x)\stackrel{I.H.}{=}x P_{N-1}(x)-P_{N-2}(x)=P_N(x).\tag{8}
$$

Thus, by induction Lemma 2 is proved.

Now, as the eigenvalues of a matrix are  exactly the roots of its characteristic polynomial,

**Lemma 3.** The roots of $P_n(\lambda)$ are:
$$
\lambda^{(n)}_m=2\cos\frac{\pi m}{n+1}, \quad m=1\dots n
$$
is a simple Corollary of Lemmas 1 and 2.