# Density of the roots of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

Consider the vector space of continuous real valued functions on a finite interval  and the inner product defined by the integral over the interval . If we have a family of orthogonal polynomials such that their span is dense then each polynomial has exactly n distinct roots . I was wondering if these roots might be dense in the interval because i tried to think of these polynomials as interpolation polynomials.

Comment: Are you assuming these polynomials form a dense basis? Why are you assuming the roots are distinct?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/roots-of-legendre-polynomial

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that my bad , yes i am assuming the span of this set is dense ( the term in french is "Famille totale" i can't find the english equivalent )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be "Yes". I have found a proof but it is too long for me to write here . The proof is an admission exams to the french "École Polytechnique" 
here is a link to the exam [X-ENS PSI 2006](http://www.prepamag.fr/concours/pdf/enonces.pdf/2006/PSI_MATHS_X_1_2006.enonce.pdf) .I will try to write the proof in english in my spare time and add it here as soon as possible .